# How to retrieve the fields and respective values from a single document search using dotnet lucene?

Tags: lucene.net

I have a | delimited txt document in which i have fields like ScenarioId, Input value, database value
I am indexing these values.

```
doc.Add(new Field("Database value", List.Databasevalue, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
 var parser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, "Database value", analyzer);
 Console.WriteLine("Text found: {0}" + Environment.NewLine, document.Get("Database value"));
```

Scenario Id|Input value|Database value
1|Akshay|Akshay Kumar
2|Akshath|Akshath T
3|Paul|John paul
4|Abraham|Abraham Joseph
5|Morris|Morris Johnson

Since my input is only one document. I dont care about the doc number. If there is any match i need to retrieve the respective database value from the input file and respective score. How do I achieve it ? There is a Get function in Document I don't know how does it work! Can someone help me out as there is limited resources available for dotnet lucene

Comment: What's the point of using Lucene if you only have one document?

Comment: @RonC Hi Ron!We already have some default libraries for the scoring but it is not working as per our requirement.Since in lucene we have many analysers for fuzzy match capablity we thought of giving it a try!Going by your way even if we have multiple documents with multiple records.Say for eg)My hit is there in 2nd document  15 th record.How do i find out what is 15th record in the 2 nd document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still a bit unclear about what you need, but here is some sample code (in the form of an xUnit test) for indexing docs, performing a search and then reading a document back in Lucene.NET 4.8.

```
[Fact]
        public void StandardAnalyzerExample() {

            Directory indexDir = new RAMDirectory();

            Analyzer standardAnalyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48);

            IndexWriterConfig indexConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, standardAnalyzer);
            indexConfig.UseCompoundFile = true;

            IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(indexDir, indexConfig);


            SearcherManager searcherManager = new SearcherManager(writer, applyAllDeletes: true, new SearchWarmer());

            Document doc = new Document();
            doc.Add(new StringField("examplePrimaryKey", "001", Field.Store.YES));
            doc.Add(new TextField("exampleField", "Unique gifts are great gifts.", Field.Store.YES));
            writer.AddDocument(doc);

            doc = new Document();
            doc.Add(new StringField("examplePrimaryKey", "002", Field.Store.YES));
            doc.Add(new TextField("exampleField", "Everyone is gifted.", Field.Store.YES));
            writer.AddDocument(doc);

            doc = new Document();
            doc.Add(new StringField("examplePrimaryKey", "003", Field.Store.YES));
            doc.Add(new TextField("exampleField", "Gifts are meant to be shared.", Field.Store.YES));
            writer.AddDocument(doc);

            writer.Commit();

            searcherManager.MaybeRefreshBlocking();
            IndexSearcher indexSearcher = searcherManager.Acquire();
            try {
                QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, "exampleField", standardAnalyzer);
                Query query = parser.Parse("everyone");

                TopDocs topDocs = indexSearcher.Search(query, int.MaxValue);

                int numMatchingDocs = topDocs.ScoreDocs.Length;
                Assert.Equal(1, numMatchingDocs);


                Document docRead = indexSearcher.Doc(topDocs.ScoreDocs[0].Doc);     //this is how you read back a doc
                string primaryKey = docRead.Get("examplePrimaryKey");
                Assert.Equal("002", primaryKey);

            } finally {
                searcherManager.Release(indexSearcher);
            }

        }

    }
```